# cron jobs, UTC and US daylight savings time

Tags: bash, date, cron

I've got a VM who's TZ is UTC, and have a cron job which must run at 19:00 ET.  Thus, I've set it to run at 23:00.  That'll work until November 7th.

Since I don't want to have to remember to have to adjust the job start time twice a year, I'm trying to think of a Better Way.

So far, all I can think of is to run it at 23:00 and 00:00, and then in the script check the hour, but that's not so elegant.

```
hour=`TZ=America/New_York date +"%H"`
echo $hour
10

if [ $hour -eq 19 ]; then echo "run me"; else echo "don't run me"; fi
don't run me
```

Comment: Short of changing the system timezone on the VM, I can't think of an "eleganter" way to do it. At least here, all the program's requirements are contained in the code.

Comment: Note in general, use `%_H` to get the hour without the leading zero -- bash arithmetic will complain about "08" and "09" being invalid octal numbers.